# Are there noncontinuous derivations $C^1(X) → ℝ$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, differential-geometry

I’m looking for an example of a Banach space $X$ and a derivation $δ \colon C^1(X) → ℝ$ which is noncontinuous with respect to the topology of uniform convergence on $C^1(X)$, that is a $ℝ$-linear map $δ \colon C^1(X) → ℝ$ satisfying

- $∀ f, g ∈ C^1(X)\colon δ(f·g) = δ(f)·g + f·δ(g)$,¹ and
- there are maps $f ∈ C^1(X)$ and for every $n ∈ ℕ$ some $f_n ∈ C^1(X)$ such that

  - $f_n \overset{n → ∞}{\longrightarrow} f$ uniformly, but
  - not $δ(f_n) \overset{n → ∞}{\longrightarrow} δ(f)$.

If there is no such derivation, I would like to see a proof or a reference for some proof. I would particularly be interested in the case $X = ℝ^n$.

---

¹: Here, $ℝ$ is equipped with an “invisible” $C^1(X)$-module structure and $f·δ(g)$ should be interpreted accordingly. The action of $C^1(X)$ on $ℝ$ should be continuous.

Context: Think of $X = ℝ^n$, the module structure as given by evaluation at $p ∈ ℝ^n$ and $δ$ as a directional derivative, so that $f·δ(g) = f(p)·\frac{∂}{∂x}g(p)$.

Comment: Should that be $\delta \colon C^1(\mathbb{R}) \to C(\mathbb{R})$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The topology of uniform (or locally uniform, or compact) convergence is ill-suited to deal with differentiability. One needs to also require uniform (or locally uniform) convergence of the derivatives to obtain continuity of derivations.

One standard example for such a phenomenon is a sequence of functions that oscillate with increasing frequency but decreasing amplitude, e.g.

$$f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n}\cdot \sin (nx)$$

on $X = \mathbb{R}$. Then we can pick $\delta(f) = f'(0)$, which is easily verified to be a derivation, and although the above sequence converges uniformly to $0$, we have $f_n'(x) = \cos (nx)$, and so $\delta(f_n) = f_n'(0) = 1$ for all $n$.